# How to make django test framework read from live database?

Tags: python, django, xapian

I realize there's a similar question here, but this one has a different approach: I have a django app that does queries over data indexed with [djapian](http://code.google.com/p/djapian/) ; I'd like to write unit tests for this app's search component, and, obviously, I'd need the django settings module and all connections with the database active, so the test runner that django provides seems ideal. *however*, the django testing framework creates a *dummy* database and I'd hate to dump all my data to a fixture and then index it (the tests would take *forever*!);

My data isn't at risk because the tests would only *read* from the database, so, how could this be achieved? -I'm new at this whole unit testing thing, so the solution of writing a new *test runner* I read in that similar question doesn't enlighten me a bit, at least not without some details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the test cases for djapian I found something really interesting: what those guys do is use the setUp method for the TestCase class: they create an object and then use the update method for the indexer, so they effectively have a document to search for *and* a way to write controlled query tests!
For the curious, the method looks something like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    p = Person.objects.create(name="Alex")

    for i in range(self.num_entries):
        Entry.objects.create(author=p, title="Entry with number %s" % i, text="foobar " * i)

    Entry.indexer.update()
```

I think this would do, but we have to remember I'm testing a little search engine here, so this solution might be the easy way out; I can't come up with an objection, though, so if you guys have an answer that'll help define a strategy for testing this kind of webApps in python in general, it's more than welcome!

-I think I'll settle for something like this for now (I wanted to test the latency of the queries with a fully populated database also, but I think I could do that later with bench tests in [Funkload](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/))

**EDIT**: Ok, to be faithful to a solution for anyone interested, I ran into another issue: the xapian index (as stated in the comment). To solve it, I created a default test runner that changed the production xapian index for a test index (a smaller one, created with a management script). This runner is fairly simple:

```
def custom_run_tests(test_labels, verbosity=1, interactive=True, extra_tests=[]):
    """Set the test indices"""
    settings.CATEGORY_CLASSIFIER_DATA = settings.TEST_CLASSIFIER_DATA    
    return run_tests(test_labels, verbosity, interactive, extra_tests)
```

And, to use it, I simply added a setting:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'search.tests.custom_run_tests'
```

I dropped the aforementioned approach (creating the documents in the setUp) for performance and readability reasons: to test the database I needed a decent amount of documents with some text (a paragraph or two), so I ended up creating a fixture for that (I used a management command that created the documents in the real database, serialized them -writing them to a file- and then deleted 'em).
So, in the end, I didn't read from the live db at all and instead used test fixtures created with a somewhat hacky script and a custom runner, and it wasn't that hard :)